# Rendering multiple objects in WebGL

Tags: javascript, rendering, webgl

I have tried following the suggestions given as answer to [this questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21835972/multiple-objects-in-webgl?rq=1) but I still can't figure out how the "rendering flow" of a WebGL program really works.
I am simply trying to draw two triangles on a canvas, and it works in a rather non-deterministic way: sometimes both triangles are rendered, sometimes only the second one (*second* as in *the last one drawn*) is rendered.

[image: Lucky run]

[image: Out of luck]

<strike>(it appears to depend on rendering time: strangely enough, the *longer* it takes, the better the odds of ending up with both triangles rendered)</strike>. **EDIT**: not true, tried refreshing over and over and the two triangles sometimes show up on very rapid renders (~55ms), sometimes on longer-running ones (~120ms). What *does* seem to be a recurring pattern is that on the very first time the page is rendered, the two triangles show, and on subsequent repeated refreshes the red one either shows for good or for a very short lapse of time, then flickers away.
Apparently I'm missing something here, let me explain my program's flow in pseudo-code (can include the real code if need be) to see if I'm doing something wrong:

```
var canvas = new Canvas(/*...*/);
var redTriangle = new Shape(/* vertex positions & colors */);
var blueTriangle = new Shape(/* vertex positions & colors */);
canvas.add(redTriangle, blueTriangle);

canvas.init(); //compiles and links shaders, calls gl.enableVertexAttribArray()
               //for vertex attributes "position" and "color"

for(shape in canvas) {
    for(bufferType in [PositionBuffer, ColorBuffer]) {
        shape.bindBuffer(bufferType); //calls gl.bindBuffer() and gl.bufferData()
                                      //This is equivalent to the initBuffers()
                                      //function in the tutorial
    }
}

for(shape in canvas) {
    shape.draw();
    //calls:
    //-gl.bindBuffer() and gl.vertexAttribPointer() for each buffer (position & color),
    //-setMatrixUniforms()
    //-drawArrays()
    //This is equivalent to the drawScene() function in the tutorial
}
```

Despite the fact I've wrapped the instructions inside object methods in my attempt to make the use of WebGLs slightly more OO, it seems to me I have fully complied to the instructions on [this lesson](http://learningwebgl.com/lessons/lesson02/index.html) (comparing the lesson's source and my own code), hence I cannot figure out what I'm doing wrong.
I've even tried to use only one `for(shape in canvas)` loop, as so:

```
for(shape in canvas) {
    for(bufferType in [PositionBuffer, ColorBuffer]) {
        shape.bindBuffer(bufferType); //calls gl.bindBuffer() and gl.bufferData()
                                      //This is equivalent to the initBuffers()
                                      //function in the tutorial
    }
    shape.draw();
    //calls:
    //-gl.bindBuffer() and gl.vertexAttribPointer() for each buffer (position & color),
    //-setMatrixUniforms()
    //-drawArrays()
    //This is equivalent to the drawScene() function in the tutorial
}
```

but it doesn't seem to have any effect.
Any clues?

Comment: Post your real code and a fiddle

Comment: This may turn out to be quite tricky since I'm developing an AngularJS module to handle WebGLs, which in turn depends on UnderscoreJS, Node.js and [caolan's async library](https://github.com/caolan/async)... I could make a github repo, tough I'd rather not disclose it just yet since this is a thesis project that should be kept private until I present it in my final dissertation...

Comment: This pseudo code does not help in debugging your issue, so you either post your drawing related code or you're up to yourself debugging it.

Comment: Also, if you're needing 55ms-120ms to render two triangles you have some other serious problems inside your drawing loop, just saying.

Comment: Alright, here goes: https://github.com/axedre/angulargl. Thanks for your time.

Comment: Lets take this to chat:
https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/61209/rendering-multiple-objects-in-webgl

Comment: Thanks @LJ_1102, your modifications (can be seen on the repo) have solved the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm guessing the issue is that by default WebGL canvases are cleared everytime they are composited

Try changing your WebGL context creation to

```
var gl = someCanvas.getContext("webgl", { preserveDrawingBuffer: true });
```

I'm just guessing your app is doing things asynchronously which means each triangle is drawn in response to some event? So, if both events happen to come in quick enough (between a single composite) then you get both triangles. If they come on different composites then you'll only see the second one.

`preserveDrawingBuffer: true` says "don't clear after each composite". Clearing is the default because it allows certain optimizations for certain devices, specifically iOS, and the majority of WebGL apps clear at the beginning of each draw operation. Those few apps that don't clear can set `preserveDrawingBuffer: true`

In your particular case line 21 of `angulargl-canvas.js`

```
options = {alpha: false, premultipliedAlpha: false};
```

try changing it to

```
options = {alpha: false, premultipliedAlpha: false, preserveDrawingBuffer: true};
```

Comment: Yes, your diagnosis is correct: I have some asynchronous events that trigger drawing. With the option you suggested, it indeed works. Thanks very much! :)

Comment: Btw, I still can't get textures to work the way they should, i.e: if I only draw one shape (in angular-canvas.js:113 I leave `triangle[1]`) it works as I expect it to; if I draw both triangles (in angular-canvas.js:113 I write `triangle`) the second one is drawn in solid red, despite the fact I remove its color buffer the moment I apply a texture (angular-objects.js:22); any idea where the problem could reside? (branch to checkout is `master`) :-/